# Virtual webcam feature not available after building OBS-Studio from latest source code on Windows 10

Tags: visual-c++, build, windows-10, visual-studio-2019, obs-studio

I tried building [OBS Studio](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio) from latest source code. I am able to build successfully by following
https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/wiki/Install-Instructions#windows-build-directions

I am able to run final build produced at `obs-studio\build\rundir\Debug\bin\64bit\obs64` but I am not seeing option to enabling Virtual Webcam at right bottom buttons below Start Streaming.

[image]

Here are files generated by build process

```
alok@LAPTOP-DG8ME7Q5:/mnt/c/Users/alokm/obs-studio$ tree build/plugins/win-dshow/Debug/
build/plugins/win-dshow/Debug/
├── win-dshow.dll
├── win-dshow.exp
├── win-dshow.lib
└── win-dshow.pdb

alok@LAPTOP-DG8ME7Q5:/mnt/c/Users/alokm/obs-studio$ tree build/rundir/Debug/obs-plugins/64bit/
build/rundir/Debug/obs-plugins/64bit/
├── coreaudio-encoder.dll
├── coreaudio-encoder.pdb
├── decklink-captions.dll
├── decklink-captions.pdb
├── decklink-ouput-ui.dll
├── decklink-ouput-ui.pdb
├── enc-amf.dll
├── enc-amf.pdb
├── frontend-tools.dll
├── frontend-tools.pdb
├── image-source.dll
├── image-source.pdb
├── obs-ffmpeg.dll
├── obs-ffmpeg.pdb
├── obs-filters.dll
├── obs-filters.pdb
├── obs-outputs.dll
├── obs-outputs.pdb
├── obs-qsv11.dll
├── obs-qsv11.pdb
├── obs-text.dll
├── obs-text.pdb
├── obs-transitions.dll
├── obs-transitions.pdb
├── obs-vst.dll
├── obs-vst.pdb
├── obs-x264.dll
├── obs-x264.pdb
├── rtmp-services.dll
├── rtmp-services.pdb
├── text-freetype2.dll
├── text-freetype2.pdb
├── win-capture.dll
├── win-capture.pdb
├── win-decklink.dll
├── win-decklink.pdb
├── win-dshow.dll
├── win-dshow.pdb
├── win-mf.dll
├── win-mf.pdb
├── win-wasapi.dll
└── win-wasapi.pdb
```

What is wrong from my side so I am not seeing button to enable Virtual Webcam?

Comment: I'm in the same boat ... I don't understand why OBS gets built without VirtualCam when I build it myself.

Comment: Dont know why they are not updating https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/wiki/Install-Instructions to enable virtual camera. To build virtual camera you need to add option `VIRTUALCAM_GUID` in `cmake`. You can generate `GUID` from any tool. This will build virtual camera module.

Comment: Yes, should be in the instructions ... or it should build by default, like it does on MacOS.

Comment: for building virtual camera and manually registering it you can use steps mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66409614/virtual-webcam-feature-not-available-after-building-obs-studio-with-virtualcam-g

and then hardcode value `vcamEnabled = true;` in source code to make it working
if this question is helping to you then please help me to get it open. its wrongly closed :(

Answer (score 0):

This must be set to build the Virtual Camera features while building.
This is mentioned as optional in the wiki.

VIRTUALCAM_GUID - Set to any random GUID value.
Use any GUID generator : [GUID Generator](https://guidgenerator.com/)

Refer : https://obsproject.com/wiki/Install-Instructions

After generating obs.exe/obs64.exe you have to install the virtual camera,

To install an OBS Virtual Camera:

In the obs-studio installation directory
(for Visual Studio builds, this is '[build dir]/rundir/[build type]'),
run data\obs-plugins\win-dshow\virtualcam-install.bat as **administrator**.

Don't forget to uninstall your build's virtual camera before cleaning/deleting your build files.

If you already have a standard OBS Studio installation, you will need to uninstall its Virtual Camera first,

To uninstall an OBS Virtual Camera:

1. Close any applications that were using the OBS Virtual Camera.
2. In the obs-studio installation directory, run data\obs-plugins\win-dshow\virtualcam-uninstall.bat as administrator.

if still not enabled and if your machine is 64bit, do the below change
filename :  ..obs-studio\plugins\win-dshow\dshow-plugin.cpp
function : obs_module_load

change the argument for the function vcam_installed(false) to vcam_installed(true)

This change will let the application check 64bit registry entry.